# how to make a successful connection to OneNote api using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, https, microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I read the OneNote Api Documentation https://dev.onenote.com/docs

But I don´t understand how to make a request to the OneNote API with c# web application in order to get all the pages in my OneNote.

I already got the Application Id, Application Secret Id and Redirect URL, but i don´t know where do I have to use them, because I have never done and http request and the documentation only provide the following: https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages, so I don´t know how to send the id´s, redirect url and Authorization: Bearer.

Could you provide me the specific code to get a successful connection to OneNote API using Application Id, Application Secret Id and Redirect URL.
And the code structure to make a http request in order to get all the pages, notebooks, etc

I would appreciate if you could help me with this.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and we'll work from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) instead of the standalone OneNote API. Microsoft Graph includes support for [OneNote](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/onenote). There is also an [SDK for .NET available](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph). There are also code samples for [ASP.NET](http://aka.ms/aspnetgraphsamples), [UWP](http://aka.ms/uwpgraphsamples) and [Xamarin](https://aka.ms/xamaringraphsamples).

Before you can use the Graph API (or most any REST API for that matter), you will need to [obtain an authorization token](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview) (i.e. the bearer token you referred to in your question). There are [libraries available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-libraries#microsoft-supported-client-libraries) for simplifying this process. Behind the scenes, these libraries are executing an OAUTH 2.0 flow. You can read about what is going on under the covers [here](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the link they have on the OneNote Dev page is broken. The team has put together a public repository that contains a bunch of sample code in a myriad of languages including C#.

1. [This is the main repo](https://github.com/OneNoteDev)
2. [Web API (ASP.NET Core) Repo](https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteApiSampleAspNetCore)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to understand these concepts is to look at sample code that does authentication. I recommend this sample:

https://github.com/OneNoteDev/MsGraph_OneNoteApiSampleAspNetCore

Btw - the demo is here: https://onenoteapisamplegraph.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone I have Checked all the links that you provided me and they were very useful, I did a connection to Microsoft Graph with the authorization token and I got access to my OneNote pages.

Thank you for your help.